# Storing Sort Order in Database: match the business logic or the application logic?

Tags: database, sorting, business-logic, logic

Take a profile page for a job applicant with a list of names in a form with typical CRUD:

- Resume Name:
- Altenrate Name 1:
- Alternate Name 2:
- Alternate Name 3:

Assuming we have some sort of `Names` table for this one-to-many relationship between an applicant and their names, we want to make sure to preserve the order of the names as they were entered. So we make a `AlternateNameSortOrder` column where, in my opinion, Resume Name's sort order is `null` as it's not an Alternate Name (and can have an `IsResume` column. This also sets us up for other fields that may not be "alternate", like preferred, background check, birth name, etc.

When it comes to storing `AlternateNameSortOrder` in the database, do you start your index counting with regards to application logic - that is, 0 (zero) - or do you start the count with regards to your business logic - where in reality the sort order matches the # for the name. That is to say, you would store a `1` for the **Alternate Name 1** field instead of `0`.

Comment: You have got two alternatives. Generally they are totally equal, doesn't matter the tiniest bit. In your specific situation: do you see any advantages of one vs. the other? My last resort for such decisions is usually: consistency (with other code in the codebase/system/company) over opinion.

Comment: As for your question, the business logic almost certainly *isn't* that the first name should have the index 1, the second name index 2, etc., it's that the order should be preserved. Unless there's something else in the business that explicitly relies on a particular indexing scheme (rather than just on the *sorting order*), the business logic is the same whether you use `0, 1, 2,...` or `10, 21, 103,...` or `DateTime1, DateTime2, DateTime3, ...`. So the key concern is not 0-based vs 1-based indexing, but rather how to support this ordering requirement using the tools available to you.

Comment: I previously left a comment about your question being written in a confusing way, with a lot of information being extraneous to the core of what you're asking, but apparently, my wording was a bit too harsh, so it looks like a mod deleted that comment. Nevertheless, I feel you should have this feedback as well, as it could help you ask better questions. I don't think your question should get a downvote, or a close vote, but I hope my comment might provide some context/insight with regard to the 2 close votes that are already there, since no other feedback was provided.

Answer (score 2):

A sort index should just be any integer that can be used for comparisons. Don't give it a dual purpose by attaching additional significance.

Then it doesn't matter where you start.